# SQL - Поиск подстрок в строке, удовлетворяющих условию

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, sql-server, запрос

Задача такая. Есть таблица с колонкой, в которой хранятся строки. Например, 2 записи в таблице:

- значение в колонке у первой записи: *"<!test><!innertest>car</!innertest></!test><!test><!innersupertest>car2</!innersupertest></!test>"*
- значение в колонке у второй записи: *"<!test><!innersupertest>car1</!innersupertest></!test>"*

Нужен запрос, который для каждой записи в таблице будет проверять данную колонку на существование подстрок *"<!test>...</!test>"*, в которых не существет подстроки *"<!innersupertest>...</!innersupertest>"*.
То есть для первой записи мы получим 2 подстроки *"<!test>...</!test>"*:

- *<!test><!innertest>car</!innertest></!test>*
- *<!test><!innersupertest>car2</!innersupertest></!test>*

Из них нам подойдет 1-я, потому что там нет *"<!innersupertest>...</!innersupertest>"*. Значит, первая запись в таблице подошла.

Для второй записи мы получим 1 подстроку *"<!test>...</!test>"*:

- *<!test><!innersupertest>car1</!innersupertest></!test>*

В ней есть подстрока *"<!innersupertest>...</!innersupertest>"*, значит вся запись не подходит.

Я пытаюсь понять, можно ли это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений, но пока не получилось.
За помощь буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Ну если нет никаких дополнительных условий или нюансов, то вам достаточно проверить, если хоть одна подходящая запись `<!test><!innertest>.*</!innertest></!test>`

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно Вас понял. Мне нужно найти запись, у которой в наборах подстрок "<!test>...</!test>" есть такой элемент, внутри которого нет <!innersupertest>...</!innersupertest>

Comment: Не до конца понял условие сначала, думал можно пойти от обратного. Попробуйте так: `<!test>(?!<!innersupertest>).*?<\/!test>`. Можно глянуть тут: https://regex101.com/r/CYW9sL/1 Хотя сейчас у меня почему-то браузер ругается на безопасность сайта regex101, приходится подтверждать переход.